# Selecting an item on Android web browser

Tags: android, mobile-webkit

When I tap (click) a link (or any selectable item) in a web page on Android web browser, the link/item is being highlighted (a thin orange line is draw around the selected item).
Does anyone know whether this behavior can be eliminate and how.

Thanks in advance,
Oded

Answer (score 3):

Behold the magic [[credit](http://www.mail-archive.com/android-developers@googlegroups.com/msg20763.html)]:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Android Link Test</title>
        <style type="text/css">
        a {
            -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <a href="http://www.google.com/">Hello, World!</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Tested on Android 2.1. No more orange-iness with that bit of CSS applied.